# Indexed Hilchos Niddah of the Ramban

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, niddah, ramban

At the end of the *Chiddushei HaRamban* on *maseches Niddah*, there is a small concise summary of the Ramban's halachic conclusions in *hilchos niddah*. Topics are grouped together in chapters, but there is no apparent order which follows the order of the *masechta* or anything else I can discern.

Is there any published index of the Ramban's Hilchos Niddah, or anyone who has mapped how to find where the halacha of the Ramban is from either the Mishneh Torah of the Rambam or the Shulchan Aruch?

Comment: tha Ramban predates the Shulchan Aurch by a few hundred years